# js/ nodejs basic beginner server for POST method using request.on() and querystring.parse()

Tags: javascript, node.js, post

I'm starting to learn some nodejs in my web classes after javascript to make some simple servers, and with this example below:

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');


function onRequest(request, response) {

    if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';

        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;  // data sent via http protocol will always be sent as a string and can be concatenated
            // if body > 1e6 === 1* Math.pow(10,6) ~~~ 1MB
            // flood attack or faulty client
            // (code 413: request entity too large), kill request
            if (body.length > 1e6) {
                response.writeHead(413, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'}).end();
                request.connection.destroy();
            }
        });            // end of data communication: body will contain all the parameters of the query 

        request.on('end',function(){
            var POST = querystring.parse(body);
            // now to get the different parameters use // POST.<field name>  e.g. POST.user
            response.end('Hello, ' + POST.firstname + ' ' + POST.lastname);

        });
    }


}

var server = http.createServer(onRequest);

server.listen(3000);
```

I have understood up to this point but have trouble looking up and understanding the request.on() and querystring.parse() portions of this code. I'll highlight them for more clarity below the exact parts I'm confused with.

1) request.on()

So I've read that request.on('data') will have nodejs set a listener for the event of receiving a chunk of data. So with the example above this part:

```
request.on('data', function (data) {
                body += data;  
                if (body.length > 1e6) {
                    response.writeHead(413, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'}).end();
                    request.connection.destroy();
                }
```

It's taking a second parameter as a callback function that takes the first parameter 'data' again. This is what I'm confused with, what is it trying to do here with the second parameter?

2) request.on('end') and querystring.parse()

I read that request.on('end') will have nodejs set a listener for the signal that the data upload **completed**, so this code below:

```
request.on('end',function(){
                var POST = querystring.parse(body);
                // now to get the different parameters use // POST.<field name>  e.g. POST.user
                response.end('Hello, ' + POST.firstname + ' ' + POST.lastname);

            }
```

Inside request.on('end') we make a new variable called POSTand set it equal to `querystring.parse(body)` with `body` being the previous variable of all the data combined. How does it go from this `querystring.parse(body)` and apply `.firstname` on it (`POST.firstname`) and access that component of it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: still nobody knows an answer to any of these?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question:

> It's taking a second parameter as a callback function that takes the first parameter 'data' again. This is what I'm confused with, what is it trying to do here with the second parameter?

So what you're doing here is defining a listener function to be called each time the `request` fires a `data` event. You may be able to see it clearer in the following manner:

```
request.on('data', onChunkReceived)

function onChunkReceived (data) {
  body += data

  if body > 1e6 === 1* Math.pow(10,6) ~~~ 1MB
    if (body.length > 1e6) {
      response.writeHead(413, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'}).end();
      request.connection.destroy();
    }
}
```

What you're doing is defining a function, which takes a `data` parameter; don't get too hung up in the fact that the event name and the parameter name that was chosen are the same; there's no reason you couldn't name it whatever you want:

```
request.on('data', onChunkReceived)

function onChunkReceived (chunk) {
  body += chunk

  if body > 1e6 === 1* Math.pow(10,6) ~~~ 1MB
    if (body.length > 1e6) {
      response.writeHead(413, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'}).end();
      request.connection.destroy();
    }
}
```

...will act exactly the same way. So again: `data` is the name of the event, and you're defining a function that receives each chunk of data as the server receives it; in your example above the function is just anonymous function that is in-line, as I've reformatted the snippet above it's a separate named function.

Now to your second question:

> Inside request.on('end') we make a new variable called POSTand set it equal to querystring.parse(body) with body being the previous variable of all the data combined. How does it go from this querystring.parse(body) and apply .firstname on it (POST.firstname) and access that component of it?

The `querystring.parse` method takes a string in a specific format, and parses it into a Javascript object. The [Node.js docs on querystring](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v4.x/docs/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options) explain it far better than I will be able to here. So, I can only assume that the example you're working from expects that the body will be in a specific format, that is [form encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type) meaning that it's in the format of the following:

`firstname=Dan&lastname=Takahashi`

When you call `querystring.parse` on that string, you'll be returned an object that looks like:

```
POST = {
  "firstname": "Dan",
  "lastname": "Takahashi"
}
```

Which you can then address as you say above: `POST.firstname` which will be "Dan" and `POST.lastname`, which will be "Takahashi".

Comment: Thank you for the clear and concise explanations. For the second part the `querystring.parse(body)` means that its using this method on the variable `body` which is the sum of all the data received right? So does that mean the data received will have to be in the form you mentioned like: `firstname=Dan&lastname=Takahashi` otherwise the `POST.firstname` wouldn't be able to get the first name out of it for example? How is it that the data received would always be in this form so that we can call querystring.parse().firstname on it?

Comment: @darkphoton Yes, the data received will have to be in that format for the example to work correctly. What this means is that whatever client is POST-ing the data will need to send in that format (which is knows as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`). This is called a "mimetype". When a client sends data via HTTP, it sets a "content-type" header that says "this is the format that i'm sending data in". In a real situation, you would read that header, decide if you can handle the type it specifies, and deal with it accordingly. In this simple example you posted, it is built assuming a format.

Answer (score 0):

Questions 1 & 2 deal with the http request data stream and allow you to inject your code to do custom activities like save the stream to a buffer/var for later use.

If you want to query the POST parameters you can simply use the bodyparser node module https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

to query the parameters using object dot notation.   For example req.body.form_field_name

body-parser is a nice module to use to get quick access to data passed along in a POST/PUT method.

Express keeps the raw body data hidden and you'll need to use a module similar to body-parser to get access.  Please note this is a read only copy of the body content.

Cheers.

PS if body-parser doesn't address your immediate need, check out

1. github.com/stream-utils/raw-body
2. github.com/moscartong/express-rawbody